# How can I stop someone from changing the gcloud profile?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-iam

Multiple users will be logging into same compute engine using same username. How can I stop anyone from changing the gcloud configs, like account, project or zone?

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you say "gcloud configs", where are these properties set? On the Compute Engine VM?  Are you using the VM as a launchpad to run other `gcloud` commands? Customarily, you should **not** share identities across multiple users because, neither you, nor the machine, can tell the difference between them (and thus, stop one person logging in as the user, from changing things that any other person logging in as the same user, has changed). If you explain more about your configuration and the solution you're developing, we can help more.

Comment: Basically the users must be running all the commands only through the service account. They should be stopped from using their own identity in gcloud when they are using this VM. How can I enforce this?

Comment: Yes, using a Service Account is the correct solution. Service Accounts exist to provide identities to software rather than individual human accounts. Without knowing more about your solution, one way to address this could be to provide your users with a web app that triggers the process on the VM. The web app could be as simple as a GET that, requires authentication (using the user's human account via OAuth) and, if authenticated, the web app runs the process on the VM using the Service Account. The response from the process could be delivered to the user as the response to the GET.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to solve that is not obvious because the pattern is not good.

You have a compute engine in the Cloud. That [compute engine has an identity](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts). You can change it, you can grant permission on that identity.

The user can log into the VM, because he has the permission to access it, and then he is able to use the VM and the attached service account (with the attached permission) to access different services.

If you have different users, many can access to the same VM and use the same VM identity to access to the same services with the same permissions.

If some users have different privilege, it's cloud!! Create another VM, with another service account, with another permissions!!

You are worry about the cost? Stop the VM when they aren't used.

The users must use the same data? You can attach a persistent disk to several Compute Engine in read only mode. Or use filestore to have a R/W storage space.

---

With that correct design, you haven't to use your personal accounts on VM on Google Cloud, only on your personal computer.

In addition, it's dangerous to continue in your way, because if a user forget to perform a `gcloud auth login`, they will use the credentials of the previously logged user and he will perform thing on their behalf!!

Comment: Yes, it is dangerous because of possibility of forgetting to perform a gcloud auth login. So what I need is, they should not be able to change the gcloud auth. Whatever command they run, it should be only through the service account attached to the VM. Is there any possibility for that ?

Comment: No automatically. Changing the pattern is a better option that custom code

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal to use the same username and password to log into a project because there is no way to determine who changed something within the project.  Your question is lacking lots of information, but if your project is a GCP project, then you have to consider using the IAM (Identity and Access Management).  If all users are using the same credentials, they can change configuration, account, project or zone, if they have the proper role to make those changes in the project. If you are the owner of the project, you can control what they can do with the project using roles. The IAM tool is very useful because it grants you a way to control what each user can do and cannot.  Here are some examples of a [few roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions):

> roles/viewer: Permissions for read-only actions that do not affect state, such as viewing (but not modifying) existing resources or data.

> roles/editor:  All viewer permissions, plus permissions for actions that modify state, such as changing existing resources.

> roles/owner: All Editor permissions and permissions for the following actions:
>
> 1. Manage roles and permissions for a project and all resources within the project.
> 2. Set up billing for a project.

By segmenting your project, you can limit what each member of the project is doing. You can let some members run code, deploy an application, others have control over the network configuration. Using different account and roles, you can use the build in “activity” feature in the GCP main page to track the changes made by any user (examples of the feature):

[image]

[image]

There are many [user roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined) that control each aspect of the project.

Here is some documentation that you can find useful to understand a bit more about the different types of roles in the GCP projects:

[Overview of how IAM works](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).

[Introduction to the Organization Policy Service](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview).

[Manage access to projects, folders, and organizations](http://Manage%20access%20to%20projects,%20folders,%20and%20organizations) .